# Change Split View Controller Navigation Bar Colour

Tags: ios, swift

I have a split view controller and I want to change the navigation bar colour.
Using the below in app delegate I have changed the colour of the detail screen (right).
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

But I can't seem to figure out how to change the bar of the navigation controller (left).

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is the navigation controller an output into your view controller? If so, you can access it that way and assign the color the same way you assigned the first one.

Comment: So far I have just got the split view controller template.
No other changes have been made - Im new to iOS development so appologies for lack of understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template provides you a MasterViewController (the left) and a DetailViewController (the right). It is the same code in both the MasterViewController and the DetailViewController, likely in `viewDidLoad`. You have it right, although there is an optional you are missing:

```
if let navContr = self.navigationController {
    navContr.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}
```